# How to change selection of NSMatrix in IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmatrix

I have `NSRadioModeMatrix` with 3 cells. `- (IBAction) EnableProxy:(id)inSender` is connected to `NSRadioModeMatrix`

```
- (IBAction) EnableProxy:(id)sender
{   

    if ([[sender selectedCell] tag]==2)
    { 

/*(gdb) p (int)[[inSender selectedCell] tag]
$1 = 2*/
        if (condition) {
             // select cell with tag 0
            [sender selectCellAtRow:0 column:0]; // This is not working
        }
        /*(gdb) p (int)[[inSender selectedCell] tag]
$2 = 1*/
    }
}// selection is not visible
```

When condition is true. selection is going back to tag 2(old selected cell).[Sample project](https://www.idrivesync.com/share/view?k=tUaphmK2f2YieLOivgdKtxjOZ3mE191I).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, this is the intended behavior, and for good reason.

[image]

Given the above UI, if a user clicks on `C`, they expect `C` to become selected. If instead, a user clicks on `C` and `A` becomes selected, you have a confused (and potentially frustrated) user. Indeed, implementing this type of behavior violates the [OS X Human Interface Guidelines for Radio Buttons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-BIAHBFAD).

That said, I'll move on to how you can implement the behavior you want. Basically, the reason why when you select `C`, the immediate call to select `A` doesn't seem to succeed is that, technically speaking, `C` is still in the process of being selected. In other words, a simplified timeline of the events would look like the following:

1. begin click on matrix
2. `EnableProxy:` method called
3. matrix immediately told to select `A`
4. finished click on matrix and `C` is finally completely selected

In order to achieve the results you want, instead of immediately telling the matrix to select `A`, you'll need to "queue" the request up like the following code does:

```
- (IBAction) EnableProxy:(id)inSender {
    if ([[inSender selectedCell] tag] == 2) {
//        [mProxyEnable selectCellAtRow:0 column:0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(selectFirstMatrixRow) withObject:nil
                                                              afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}

- (void)selectFirstMatrixRow {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [mProxyEnable selectCellAtRow:0 column:0];
}
```

By using `[self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`, you basically say "call this method as soon as possible". Doing so lets `C` be fully selected before that method is called, which allows the results you want. In other words, the timeline of events would look like this:

1. begin click on matrix
2. `EnableProxy:` method called
3. finished click on matrix and `C` is finally completely selected
4. --------- control returns to normal event loop ---------
5. `selectFirstMatrixRow` method called
6. matrix selects `A`

Comment: @NSGod I like how your name is NSGod. Let me guess, do you call your child classes called NSJesus?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the above answer provided by NSGod, This can be also achieved using GCD rather giving the unnecessary delay with 0.0

```
ViewController * __weak weakRef = self;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakRef selectFirstMatrixRow];
        });
```